# How to fix following error : 'strdup, _snprintf_s not declared' while compiling with mingw32?

Tags: mingw32

The code that I am compiling was initially built on Visual Studio 2013. Now I am trying to compile the same code with mingw32 toolset with -std=c++0x. But, it is unable to find declaration for certain functions like strdup and _snprintf_s. How do I resolve it ?

Comment: I am not sure if `_snprintf_s` is present in MinGW. I think all "safe" functions are missing, with the motivation that `snprintf` is safe, correctly used.

Comment: @user877329 right, had to use snprintf() instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, this happens with the latest Mingw.Try to replace -std=c++11 with -std=gnu++0x

Comment: Thanks. The 'strdup' error was handled by changing the above flag.